# multiple options for re

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the word 'single report' from this sentence using re but it returns '' values as well
help please
Here's an example:

```
import re
txt = "they were looking for a single report not an ongoing service access to our products and therefore our solution was irrelevant for them currently even though the subscription would include what they were looking for this would not be an arr deal and did not match what they were looking to pay for a one off report and therefore they were not interested in moving forward "
x = re.findall(r'one report|1 report|single report|', txt)
print(x)
```

The result is:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'single report', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

How can I get rid of all of the '' without changing the option to also get 'one report' or '1 report'?

Comment: Try to remove trailing vertical bar

Comment: I don't think you want that last `|` at the end of your pattern. That's matching an empty space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `|` matches no characters, so remove it:

```
x = re.findall(r'one report|1 report|single report', txt)
```

Thanks for @JvdV to point out another great way to do it:

```
x = re.findall(r'(?:one|1|single) report', txt)
```

Comment: Upvoted =). Maybe just a recommendation but OP seems to use `report` repetative. So another way would be: `x = re.findall(r'(?:one|1|single) report', txt)` with a non-capturing group =)